While using defer, useLoaderData() returns the previous fetched results instead of a promise
I am experiencing a problem with useLoaderData() hook, While using react-router Form component with GET method.  I have programmed the loader to return deferred data, and I am using Suspense in my component to render a Loading icon until the promise is resolved. This works as intended on the initial render, i.e:

Loader runs.
Component renders and runs the Suspense fallback.
Data is Fetched from the API
The promise resolves and the callback function in Await runs.

However, when i submit the form again, the following happens:

Loader runs
Component renders, but this time the useLoaderData() returns the previously fetched result instead of the promise
The callback function in Await runs(as there is no promise to resolve).
The data is fetched from the API.(The URL also doesn't switch until this point)
Component re-renders, and useLoaderData() returns the new fetched data.
The callback function in Await re-runs.

App component(Router):
function App() {
  const browserRouter = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={<HomePage />}
        loader={HomePageLoader}
      />
    )
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <RouterProvider router={browserRouter} />
    </>
  );
}

Function interacting with API()
export async function fetchDataFromColorAPI(targetUrl: string) {
  const response = await fetch(targetUrl);
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error("Error occurred with API");
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log("API data:  ",data.colors);
  return getColorsInfo(data.colors);
}

Loader Function:
export function loader({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  console.log("in loader");
  const params = new URL(request.url).searchParams;
  const { color, mode, count } = getSearchParams(params); //utility function to get search parameters
  const baseUrl = "https://www.thecolorapi.com/scheme";
  const searchQuery = `?hex=${color}&mode=${mode}&count=${count}&format=json`;

  return defer({ colorsInfo: fetchDataFromColorAPI(baseUrl + searchQuery) });
}

Component calling useLoaderData():
export default function HomePage() {
  console.log("In component");

  const data = useLoaderData() as LoaderData;
  function renderPallet(colorsInfo: Color[]) {
    console.log("promise resolved, Values recieved: ", colorsInfo);
    return <Pallet colorsInfo={colorsInfo} />;
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <InputForm />
      <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading....</h1>}>
        <Await resolve={data.colorsInfo}>{renderPallet}</Await>
      </Suspense>
    </main>
  );
}


Form:
<Form  replace className="form">
  //Input fields
</Form>

I tried going through the docs, but couldn't find the reason for this. My guess is that this may be happening because of some optimization being done by React or React-Router.
Can someone explain this behaviour specifically how loader and useLoaderData() behave when combined with React-Router Form "GET" method. How can I force the useLoaderData() hook to return a promise instead of the previous fetched result.
Github Respository: https://github.com/Azfar731/ColorPicker.git

Once a route is loaded, it's not going to re-load unless you navigate away first. In other words, once a route has loaded the first time, any additional actions can only re-render the already mounted route component and re-run any route loaders instead of doing a full loading/mounting cycle.

After route actions are called, the data will be revalidated
automatically and return the latest result from your loader.
Note that useLoaderData does not initiate a fetch. It simply reads the
result of a fetch React Router manages internally, so you don't need
to worry about it refetching when it re-renders for reasons outside of
routing.
This also means data returned is stable between renders, so you can
safely pass it to dependency arrays in React hooks like useEffect. It
only changes when the loader is called again after actions or certain
navigations. In these cases the identity will change (even if the
values don't).

This matches what you are observing where the previously fetched result is still provided to the component until it's replaced by the next fetch.
I think you can use the useNavigation hook to handle when the route's loader is fetching in response to a route or form action being triggered. See specifically navigation.state for complete details.
Example:
import { ...., useNavigation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function HomePage() {
  const data = useLoaderData() as LoaderData;
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  // Are we reloading after an action?
  const isReloading =
    navigation.state === "loading" &&
    navigation.formData != null &&
    navigation.formAction === navigation.location.pathname;

  // Are we redirecting after an action?
  const isRedirecting =
    navigation.state === "loading" &&
    navigation.formData != null &&
    navigation.formAction !== navigation.location.pathname;

  function renderPallet(colorsInfo: Color[]) {
    console.log("promise resolved, Values received: ", colorsInfo);
    return <Pallet colorsInfo={colorsInfo} />;
  }

  return (
    <main>
      {(isReloading || isRedirecting) && <h1>Loading....</h1>}
      <InputForm />
      <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading....</h1>}>
        <Await resolve={data.colorsInfo}>{renderPallet}</Await>
      </Suspense>
    </main>
  );
}


This solved my problem. However, I am getting different results for navigation methods from what is mentioned in the documentation. The documentation states that in the case of GET form submission: navigation.formAction, navigation.formData and navigation.formMethod will be empty.
However, by checking through chrome dev tools I get the following values while my navigation.state is set to"loading":
navigation.formMethod: get,
navigation.formAction: [path]+[searchquery],
navigation.formData: Object.
What is the documentation referring to?

@azfarrazzaq I think the docs are referring to the navigation object and properties, but the documentation is also known to sometimes be a bit sparse on details. For example, the upgrade from RRD v5 to v6 I had to learn much of the new behaviors through trial-and-error to understand it, and have made MRs to update docs where I thought improvements could be made.
